# subtract two dates and show result in date formate

Tags: php, datediff

i m tried hard to get the date in the date formate after subtracting 
two dates but not getting the correct result ,and the result is 1970-01-07 05:00:00 but i require the result 2013-02-07 12:02:00

```
$start_date =strtotime('2013-02-13 12:02:00');
$end_date =strtotime('2013-02-20 12:02:00');
$total = ($start_date - $end_date);
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$total);
```

Comment: The result of subtracting one date from another is a period, not another date. Why on earth would it be 2013-02-07 12:02:00?

Comment: @user1869193, by the way this is not the difference by any means

Answer (score 2):

As of PHP 5.3 you can use the [`DateTime::diff()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) method together with the [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/de/class.dateinterval.php) class for that:

```
<?php

$start = new DateTime('2013-02-13 12:02:00');
$end   = new DateTime('2013-02-20 12:02:00');

$interval = $end->diff($start);
echo $interval->format('%Y-%M-%D %H:%I:%S');
```

In addition, it is the supposed way to do as of PHP5.3, as it handle timezones, daylight saving times (leap hours) and leap years properly.

Answer (score 2):

you are getting the correct result as after subtracting two date result is 7 days which is added to default date 1970-01-01

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below

```
$date2 ='2013-02-13 12:02:00';
$date1 ='2013-02-20 12:02:00';

$diff = abs(strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1));

$years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));
$months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));
$days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));

printf("%d years, %d months, %d days\n", $years, $months, $days);
```